# How to solve The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Tickets_AspNetUsers_UserId"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I need help since I stuck here and I don't know where I made mistake and what is wrong with my code.
When I want too update records in my database I get this kind of error

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Tickets_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "VmSTicketing", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated`.

Since I look all around the google and forums and I can noto figure out what is wrong here. Whatever I try I always come back to same point.

SO far here is my model

```
public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Opis")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public string DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

        [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka")]
        public DateTime Answered { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Vrsta tiketa")]
        public int TicketTypeID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("TicketTypeID")]
        public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; } = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();


    }
```

And here is my controller action

```
public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {
            IEnumerable<TicketType> TTList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll();
            TicketVM ticketVM = new()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                }),
                ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser(),
                Client = new Client()
            };


            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }

            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

And here is my `HttpPost` action which made problem

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);
                    ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    ticketVM = new()
                    {
                        Ticket = new Ticket(),
                        TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = i.Name,
                            Value = i.Id.ToString()
                        }),
                        ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser(),
                        Client = new Client()
                    };
                    
                    //ticketVM.Ticket.Status = ((TicketStatus)Convert.ToInt32(ticketVM.Ticket.Status)).ToString();
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            //else
            //{
            //    ticketVM.TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
            //    {
            //        Text = i.Name,
            //        Value = i.Id.ToString()
            //    });

            //    if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id != 0)
            //    {
            //        ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(ticketVM.Ticket.Id);
            //    }
            //}
            //_unitOfwork.Save();
            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

SO far I try to change in my model

```
 public int UserId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser ")]
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Please guys be human and help me to solve this kind of error since I lost a hour and hour to figure out what I made wrong here.
Cheers !

**UPDATE**

Ok, so. After **@King King** say that problem is in  `if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)` I move ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser before `if` block

```
    [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
{
    var userName = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    var user = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
        {
            ticketVM.Ticket.Status = TicketStatus.Otvoren.ToString();
            _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
        }
        else
        {
            _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
            ticketVM.Ticket.Status = ((TicketStatus)Convert.ToInt32(ticketVM.Ticket.Status)).ToString();
        }

        _unitOfwork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    else
    {
        ticketVM.TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = i.Name,
            Value = i.Id.ToString()
        });

        if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id != 0)
        {
            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(ticketVM.Ticket.Id);
        }

    }
    return View(ticketVM);
}
```

Right now confict gone, but still I have problem with `ApplicationUser`
After I login as Administrator and try to update `POST A` from `USER A` it automatically  update ApplicationUser column and USER A is not assignt to ticket anymore

**DEMO**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICy9a.jpg

**TicketVM**

```
 public class TicketVM
    {
        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }

        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TicketTypeList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Ime")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Adresa")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Grad")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postanski broj")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public int? ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string Role { get; set; }      

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ClientList { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: looks like the error occurs in this switch `ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0`, my guess is that the `_unitOfwork.Ticket.Add` will cascade its adding through the whole ticket, including the property `ApplicationUser`. That user is loaded with an Id (existing user) so it should be updated or ignored, not added. It's strange that EFCore cannot detect that already tracked item to ignore it. Here you can try `_unitOfwork.Ticket.Add` ***first*** before setting the `ApplicationUser`, if possible setting the FK of `ApplicationUser` is enough (instead of setting the whole object)

Comment: Since this part works fine I didn't notice anything wroong there, only the problem start in `else block` and I try to figure out why. Since I also change FK in my model 
`[ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }`

Comment: it can't be in the else block, because there you just update an empty `Ticket`, which is weird. It does not even involve the user (which has the error of updating). Looks like you did not post the actual code for that part.

Comment: there are 2 else blocks here, I talked about the one that is not commented.

Comment: Please tell me what part of code do you need, it is not problem I will post.

Comment: I mean if you know exactly where the error is thrown (as you said in some `else` block), just post the code there as much as possible (but usually in the same scope). There are 2 else blocks, the uncommented one cannot cause error (updating an empty ticket), the other block is commented so I'm not sure if that's where the error is thrown.

Comment: I solve the problem but in half :) 
The problem is 
`ticketVM.Ticket.ApplicationUser = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == userName);`

Comment: But now, after I update entity ApplicationUser column is changed to user who update records, but I need ApplicationUser to Created entity

Comment: that's a line of code and it looks exactly like what you posted, so it's unclear what the actual problem with it here. You should update your question with new info you've just discovered.

Comment: Let me update question.

Comment: @KingKing I update my question right now, and I add new code and I add DEMO

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230338/discussion-between-rayor-and-king-king).

Comment: looks like your new setting of `ApplicationUser` ***overrides*** the one already loaded into `ticketVM`, that's why it works without error but with wrong business logic. So you need to come back with your original issue. Looking at the error again, I see that it's an FK constraint error (not PK).

Comment: the `UserId` in the ticket may point to a ***non-existent*** user in `ApplicationUser`. That's your exact issue. So that's part of issue related to how your client can send a non-existent id like that. Of course the server code can check to see if it's existed to respond with a friendly error. Otherwise it's not very mandatory because it will end up with an error. Normally if your client works, everything should just work with some rare time of such an error thrown.

Comment: I update my question. Please look at update version again in the end

Comment: see my comments above, I think I guessed it right. So you may have to fix your client code (where you build an instance of `Ticket` having a non-existent `UserId`). If you set `ApplicationUser` (as you did) to an instance loaded from the db, the `UserId` then is overwritten with that loaded user id (which does exist). That's why the error is gone, but the logic is wrong, because the overwritten user id is not from the view model.

Comment: you can start by setting a breakpoint right at the beginning of your action method and debug it to see the actual value of `UserId` from the ticket view model. You should see a value that is not existed (query your db to confirm that).

Comment: @KingKing Yes, you are right. `Ticket` show UserId as `0`. Hmmmm

Comment: @KingKing What I made wrong here ? UserId Is set to `0`

Comment: as I said, it's part of the client code, your view model somehow is not bound with that value. E.g: on your client side, you have a dropdownlist to select the user, but somehow that selected user is not bound to the view model on the server side. I think you may have to separate that into another question, it surely involves the client code (javascript, ...). This time you just need to confirm that the `UserId` is sent correctly from the client and bound to the `ticketVM`.

Comment: @KingKing Thank you for your help man and advice !